# How can I create .o and .a files in ELF format for Windows for the use with C++Builder 10.3.3?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++builder, elf, coff

I'm working with Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3.3, and would like to use OpenCV with it. However, the precompiled OpenCV pack is **precompiled with Visual Studio**, which uses the **COFF** format. However, the C++Builder 64-bit compiler uses the **ELF** format **under Windows**, per [Upgrading Existing C++ Projects to 64-bit Windows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Upgrading_Existing_C%2B%2B_Projects_to_64-bit_Windows):

> ### Object and Library File Format
>
> - BCC32 and its associated tools use OMF in .obj and .lib files.
> - BCC64 uses ELF in .o and .a files.

Of course, I tried to compile the OpenCV source code with C++Builder, but I failed miserably. A Google search didn't find anything really helpful either, except that others also didn't succeed.

Does anyone know a **CMake-compatible** compiler that can generate **object files (`.o`)** and **static libraries (`.a`)** for **Windows** to compile OpenCV (for Windows, not for Linux, because BCC64.EXE is a Windows compiler)?

Comment: I don't think this is possible - if you use precompiled MSVC object file format then it's incompatible with other object file formats  . This is why we have open source and/or stable binary interfaces  .   Perhaps you could build your OpenCV interface in MSVC or g++ or clang , and have the C++Builder GUI talk to it via some kind of IPC

Comment: What problems exactly did you have with compiling the openCV source code in C++Builder?

Comment: Alternatively, you could compile OpenCV into a DLL, and then you can create a bcc64-compatible import `.lib` using Embarcadero's [`mkexp.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B) tool. It should also be noted that Delphi has natively supported COFF libs since XE2, I wonder why C++Builder was never updated to do the same? There are 3rd party tools though, like [objconv](https://www.agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: problem with using MSVC++ compatible libs in C++Builders is usually only in either some conflicting names which a namespace statement can remedy , and or missing some `#include` and `#define` statements  prior to your lib include that is required but not present in MSVC++/GCC as that stuff is usually not present in code but in their project config and make files ... I hate that ... It is very sad but modern MSVC++ and GCC compilers/linkers behavior lead to not clear dependencies ... From what I know you even can not create stand alone executable in MSVC++ anymore

Comment: I published the error in the opencv forum, it's the last post, here is the link
https://forum.opencv.org/t/using-opencv-with-embarcadero-delphi-10-3-3-object-pascal/2485/5

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to use OpenCV with C++Builder (I couldn't write a comment because this is my first contribution!).

I could create the lib file with mkexp from the precompiled dll (opencv_world452.dll in \opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin) as Remy suggested.

But I have problems with the header files: How to set include path that the statement #include "opencv2/core.hpp" is accepted by the compiler? "core.hpp" also has such include statements. So, do we need to change all these #includes (\ instead of /)?

As a workaround you could try to use the Delphi-OpenCV library (https://github.com/Laex/Delphi-OpenCV) or install Python4Delphi in C++Builder and use OpenCV via Python.

Comment: I could compile example.cpp but I get for all cv objects unresolved external errors as follows:

[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'cv::Mat::Mat()' referenced from C:\DATA\CBUILDER10-3\TESTOPENCV\WIN64\DEBUG\FMTESTOPENCV.O

Something wrong with the import lib I guess?

Comment: yes, it is indeed a problem with the lib, Embarcadero uses ELF format for new clang compilers, have a look http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Upgrading_Existing_C%2B%2B_Projects_to_64-bit_Windows

Comment: But I made ELF lib files with mkexp as Remy suggested. I analyzed the dll(s) with Dependency Walker but all functions seem to begin with cv (and many nonsense function names!). Is openCV a C library and C++ wrappers are in the hpp files?

Comment: openCV used to be a C library, but is now almost completely re-developed in C ++

Comment: It seems that Embarcadero pushes the use of Python4Delphi for using free open source libraries instead of providing precompiled packages for use with C++Builder and Delphi.

Comment: Ralf Frankhauser the "nonsens function names" are name mangled; e.g. it's a way to provide overloaded functions that have the same name; it depens on the compiler manufaturer how the funktion names are changed